# C# Reflection why GetFields list fields that I haven't created ? How to exclude them?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This code returns fields that I created but also some system fields (I'm in WPF app) I didn't create myself:

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos;
fieldInfos = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

How to exclude the system fields and keep only my own ?

Update: these fields are not fields I inherited from my own class either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you have inherited from something other than `object` - in which case add [`DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) to your `GetFields` call:

> #### DeclaredOnly
>
> Specifies that only members declared at the level of the supplied type's 
>   hierarchy should be considered. Inherited members are not considered.

So you would have:

```
FieldInfo[] fieldInfos = this.GetType().GetFields(
     BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Comment: But since this is WPF, wouldn't it be fields of a Partial class?

Comment: @Henk - impossible to answer that without more context. But I don't know of any good way to spot `.designer.cs` fields, unless they happen to all be decorated with some attribute.

Comment: I thinks this is applied to every .Net class regardless of the development platform (Asp.Net, WPF, ..etc).

Comment: Subsequent challenge :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838717/c-reflection-how-to-set-an-event-handler-dynamically

Comment: I didn't realize until today that XAML fields are declared as internal.  This also caused problems for me when using BindingFlags.Public.